# An Installation throught wine requires KB3102810 win7 package

Tags: 22.04, wine, winetricks

I have installed a windows program on wine (ubuntu 22.04.4), now when I double click the icon to start program on the Desktop, appears a window "you need KB3102810_x64". I tryied to install it through winetricks because it's a MSU file, but the system doesn't recognize the file. I tryied with wine in win10 and win7. Is there another way to install it? Sorry for bad english. Thank you to all.